# I am found everywhere, Even in the air. What am I?

Tags: riddle

First of all, I want to say that this is my first puzzle and I hope you guys like it!

Here is the puzzle:

> I am found everywhere,
>
> Even in the air.
>
> I control the weather,
>
> but also machinery.
>
> I can destroy things with my strength,
>
> small and big.
>
> No one can win from me,
>
> No one can handle me.
>
> As long I am getting strength.
>
> My best friend is Pascal,
>
> He keeps an eye on me when I push.
>
> Not just in the air,
>
> but also in the water and in the ground.
>
> My name is used for everything by humans.
>
> Not only for scientific reasons,
>
> but also for time and social activities.
>
> **What am I?**

Comment: I am afraid, this isn't a good riddle. Riddles should generally contain some metaphors or word-play. Yours was too easy and Pascal was a dead giveaway. In the future,try to not give away the answer with a clue and use wordplay to subtly point towards the intended answer. (I downvoted)

Comment: When making riddles, try add some element of contradiction. Eg: The more I dry the wetter I get (a towel).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly

> Pressure

I am found everywhere,

Even in the air.

> Atmospheric pressure

I control the weather,

but also machinery.

> Pressure is an important factor in weather determination

I can destroy things with my strength,

small and big.

> High pressure can cause substances to crumble

No one can win from me,

No one can handle me.

> OP suggests- the phrase-can't handle the pressure

As long I am getting strength.

> Probably just filler. Strength might indicate more force

My best friend is Pascal,

He keeps an eye on me when I push.

> SI unit of Pressure is pascal

Not just in the air,

but also in the water and in the ground.

> Pressure in water, air. In deep water $P=hdg$

My name is used for everything by humans.

> Yep, we do

Not only for scientific reasons,

but also for time and social activities.

> Time-pressure, exam-pressure,Stress. Not all of them are scientific.

Comment: It seems this one was too easy. Just one comment: "No one can handle me" would indicate the common phrase "Can't handle the **pressure** ".

Comment: I'd like to comment that there's a somewhat famous riddle with the same answer, which is apparently alot more difficult, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Pressure as pascal is the unit of pressure and also it is not only applicable for scientific reasons but also for time and social activities

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE. Unfortunately, your answer to this riddle, and the explanations, were already given in the other answer, so this doesn't add any value.